# MVC5 model binding -- child objects all null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

When my parent class/model is posted back to the server and I use the BindAttribute "Bind", child objects are all null.

If I don't include the binding, then it works 
`public ActionResult SaveEdit(int id, Person person)`

For instance the person.Address property is not null, and it's properties are set based upon the form submission.

Just FYI, Address is created in the view using a EditorFor, everything is included in the request form.

But if I use Bind, it doesn't work..

```
public ActionResult SaveEdit(int id, [Bind(Include = "PersonId, AddressId, Address.AddressId, Address.Line1, Address.City, Address.State, Address.Zip")] Person person)
```

person.PersonId and person.AddressId are set correctly, but person.Address is null.

If use Bind and **multiple parameters**, like so...

```
    public ActionResult SaveEdit(int id, [Bind(Include = "PersonId")] Person person, 
       [Bind(Prefix = "Address", Include = "AddressId, Line1, City, State, Zip")] Address address)
```

It halfway works,  both object are created, neither has related properties that would normally be there.

Is this normal behavior, or have I done something wrong?

Comment: `[Bind(Include = "PersonId, AddressId, Address")]` should work, but if your needing to use `[Bind(Include ="..")]` then stop and use a view model with just the properties you need to edit instead.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: post that as an answer and I'll accept...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not shown your model, but assuming it contains properties `PersonId`, `AddressId` and `Address` where `Address` is a complex object then it needs to be

```
public ActionResult SaveEdit(int id, [Bind(Include = "PersonId, AddressId, Address")] Person person)
```

However, the better approach is to use a view model containing only those properties you are editing and avoid the use of `[Bind(Include = "properties, list")]`

Comment: just to be sure, the ".." is an abbreviation?  Or is it another bit of syntax?

Comment: Yes it just a placeholder - I was too lazy to add all the text :)